# How to run the latest Docker version of Nextclade on COVID input fasta?

Tags: docker, bioinformatics, google-genomics

I try to run the following Shell code:

```
 sudo docker run -it --rm nextstrain/nextclade:latest nextclade run --dataset-name 'sars-cov-2' - 
 -output-all  covid19.fasta # fasta file has the data I want to process
```

Nothing could be processed, changed the flags and options, nothing happens...
Do you know how to run it  in a proper way on the Linux Mint, can you advise a tutorial on this latest version, current documentation describes the older versions, Python and Deb installations are not working properly too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have coped on my own: nobody replied me, all in winter hibernation or because I am a Russian invader,  I don`t know why...who cares....

```
       sudo docker run -it --rm=True -v $PWD:/data   -u $(id -u):$(id -g) 
        nextstrain/nextclade:latest nextclade run  -d "sars-cov-2" 
       ./data/covid19.fasta  --output-all  ./data/NextcladeResults
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).